# How to color all bars in all subplots based off a name

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, seaborn, bar-chart

The goal is to mark every bar with '?' in a color different from the rest. A similar problem was already asked before, but it does not solve the problem I am facing here.

[How to color a single bar based off name](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62336190/7758804)

```
%matplotlib inline

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib as mpl
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

data=[['a','a','b'],[20,'?',18],['?','?','f'],['?','f','f'],['a','a','?']]
col_with_missting_values=['A1','A2','A3']
df=pd.DataFrame(data,columns=col_with_missting_values)

def color(coln):
    if coln=='?':
        return 'b'
    else:
        return 'r'

fig, axes = plt.subplots(1, len(col_with_missting_values), figsize=(20, 5))
for colname, ax in zip(col_with_missting_values, axes):
    (
        cr:=[color(x) for x in df[colname]],
        sns.countplot(df, x=f"{colname}", ax=ax, palette=cr),
        ax.set_xticklabels(ax.get_xticklabels(), rotation=90),
    )
```

every Bar which has a '?' should be blue but is not, while f in A2 is blue which is also wrong

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue is because you are mapping a color to every individual value in a column but a value may appear more than once. For example, if you hardcode `A2` in `cr:=[color(x) for x in df[colname]]` you will see the results are `['r', 'b', 'b', 'r', 'r']`.

But, you only have 3 bars so only the first 3 color values are used. This is why you see `f` appearing as blue for `A2`. If we only use the unique values of the column to create the color map then the columns are colored as you expect.

Change
`cr:=[color(x) for x in df[colname]]` to
`cr:=[color(x) for x in df[colname].unique()],`

Result:
[image]

Comment: **Passing `palette` without assigning `hue` is deprecated and will be removed in v0.14.0. Assign the `x` variable to `hue` and set `legend=False` for the same effect.**

Answer (score 1):

- Passing `palette` without passing `hue` is deprecated, so it's better to convert the dataframe to a long-form with [`pandas.DataFrame.melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html), and add a column for the color, which provides a column to easily create a `dict` for `palette`, and a column for `hue`.

  - This also makes plotting easier with [`sns.catplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) and [`kind='count'`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.countplot.html).
- **Tested in `python v3.12.0`, `pandas v2.1.2`, `matplotlib v3.8.1`, `seaborn v0.13.0`.**

```py
import pandas as pd
import seaborn as sns
import numpy as np

# sample data from OP
data = [['a', 'a', 'b'], [20, '?', 18], ['?', '?', 'f'],
        ['?', 'f', 'f'], ['a', 'a', '?']]
cols = ['A1', 'A2', 'A3']
df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=cols)

# convert the data to long form as required by seaborn
dfm = df.melt(var_name='variable', value_name='value')

# add a palette column
dfm['palette'] = np.where(dfm['value'].eq('?'), 'b', 'r')

# create a palette dictionary
palette = dict(dfm[['value', 'palette']].values)

# plot the data
g = sns.catplot(kind='count', data=dfm, x='value', col='variable', sharex=False,
                hue='value', palette=palette, legend=False, height=5, aspect=1)

# remove 'variable = ' from facet title if preferred
g.set_titles(template='{col_name}')

# remove xlabels if preferred
g.set(xlabel='')

# rotate xticklabels if preferred
_ = g.set_xticklabels(rotation=30)
```

[image]

#### `dfm.head()`

```
  variable value palette
0       A1     a       r
1       A1    20       r
2       A1     ?       b
3       A1     ?       b
4       A1     a       r
```

#### `palette`

```py
{'a': 'r', 20: 'r', '?': 'b', 'f': 'r', 'b': 'r', 18: 'r'}
```